# MySQL: Insert new records in one table using some specific values from another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with the following fields:

> TABLENAME: character
>
> ```
> Columns: AccountID, CharacterID, CharName, ID1, ID2, ID3, Level
> ```
>
> TABLENAME: bankitem
>
> ```
> Columns: CharID, Name, ItemID, Count, Type, ID1, ID2, ID3, Color, Effect1, Effect2, Effect3, LifeSpan, Attribute
> ```

I would like to insert new rows into table bankitem. I need to look up information from one table (character) and use some of it to as values in the second table (bankitem). I would only like to define the CharID and ID1, ID2, ID3 once, although each row would have these values.

So for example, record in character table:

```
1000, 1500, WarriorBob, 1200, 905, -2345, 180
```

**Query/Insert:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `character` 
WHERE  `CharName` LIKE  'WarriorBob'
LIMIT 0 , 1000
```

??

```
INSERT INTO bankitem (CharID, Name, ItemID, Count, Type, ID1, ID3, Color, Effect1, Effect2, Effect3, LifeSpan, Attribute)
values ('#CharacterID from WarriorBob's record in character table#', 'ZemstoneofSacrifice', '650', '1', '2', '#ID1 from WarriorBob's record in character table#', '#ID2 from WarriorBob's record in character table#', '#ID3 from WarriorBob's record in character table#', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0')
```

Comment: have you looked at the documentation of `INSERT INTO tablename SELECT ...`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert INTO MySQL FROM another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236932/insert-into-mysql-from-another-table)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0):

You would do this using `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO bankitem (CharID, Name, ItemID, Count, Type, ID1, ID3, Color, Effect1, Effect2, Effect3, LifeSpan, Attribute)
    select CharacterID, 'ZemstoneofSacrifice', '650', '1', '2', ID1, ID2, ID3, '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0'
    from character c
    where charname = 'WarriorBob';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO bankitem 
(CharID, Name, ItemID, Count, Type, ID1, ID3, Color, Effect1, Effect2, Effect3, LifeSpan, Attribute)
(select CharacterID, ZemstoneofSacrifice', '650', '1', '2', ID1, ID2, ID3, '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0' 
from character where charname = 'WarriorBob')
```

Comment: Thanks @joe-love - how would I integrate the ability to add multiple rows at the same time?