# Copy MySQL table values to duplicate table using specific column names

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to copy the values of a table accross to a new one so that I can make ALTER statements without locking the table for days on end.

However, I also want to make some changes to the table column structure. So I don't want to use *

Instead I want to be able to specify the columns like an ordinary insert statement. **But for some reason it doesn't like this syntax?**

```
INSERT INTO earnings_new 
(earning_account_id, earning_link_id, earning_ticket_id, earning_referral_id, 
earning_referral_type, earning_ad_id, earning_verified, earning_paid, earning_amount, earning_country,
earning_country_id, earning_ip, earning_hour, earning_day, earning_month, earning_year, earning_created, earning_updated) 
VALUES 
(
SELECT
earning_account_id, earning_link_id, earning_ticket_id, earning_referral_id, 
earning_referral_type, earning_ad_id, earning_verified, earning_paid, earning_amount, earning_country,
earning_country_id, earning_ip, earning_hour, earning_day, earning_month, earning_year, earning_created, earning_updated
FROM earnings
WHERE earning_month = 2 AND earning_day = 12 AND earning_hour = 13
GROUP BY earning_id
ORDER BY earning_created DESC
)
```

Comment: Maybe paste a stacktrace trace of the error given?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert INTO MySQL FROM another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236932/insert-into-mysql-from-another-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try omitting the `VALUES` keyword.

```
INSERT INTO earnings_new 
(earning_account_id, earning_link_id, earning_ticket_id, earning_referral_id, 
earning_referral_type, earning_ad_id, earning_verified, earning_paid, earning_amount, earning_country,
earning_country_id, earning_ip, earning_hour, earning_day, earning_month, earning_year, earning_created, earning_updated) 

(
SELECT
earning_account_id, earning_link_id, earning_ticket_id, earning_referral_id, 
earning_referral_type, earning_ad_id, earning_verified, earning_paid, earning_amount, earning_country,
earning_country_id, earning_ip, earning_hour, earning_day, earning_month, earning_year, earning_created, earning_updated
FROM earnings
WHERE earning_month = 2 AND earning_day = 12 AND earning_hour = 13
GROUP BY earning_id
ORDER BY earning_created DESC
)
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

Answer (score 1):

remove the `VALUES` word. its not needed in MySql

```
   INSERT INTO earnings_new
(earning_account_id, earning_link_id, earning_ticket_id, earning_referral_id, 
earning_referral_type, earning_ad_id, earning_verified, earning_paid, earning_amount, earning_country,
earning_country_id, earning_ip, earning_hour, earning_day, earning_month, earning_year, earning_created, earning_updated) 

SELECT
earning_account_id, earning_link_id, earning_ticket_id, earning_referral_id, 
earning_referral_type, earning_ad_id, earning_verified, earning_paid, earning_amount, earning_country,
earning_country_id, earning_ip, earning_hour, earning_day, earning_month, earning_year, earning_created, earning_updated
FROM earnings
WHERE earning_month = 2 AND earning_day = 12 AND earning_hour = 13
GROUP BY earning_id
ORDER BY earning_created DESC
```